# Is it posible to generate entity code for MySQL database view?

Tags: java, jhipster

I'm going to add view to my database, joining several tables. So, 
my question is: is it possible to generate entity in jhipster project for that view?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried anything? Written some code? Done a web search? Searched here? Don't just dump a research question on SO, please.

Comment: yes, i asked google , read jhipster doc https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/ ,  searched here and almost done jhipster project.  Is it good enough?

Comment: Not really. Since the mind reading plugin for SO doesn't work yet, you have to _tell_ us what research you have done, and maybe a [mcve] that demos your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, you must define a normal entity mapped to a table and then modify generated code manually:

- delete Liquibase migration generated to create the table
- edit the entity class to annotate it with `@Immutable` and `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)`
- remove write operations from entity resource controller
- remove client code and UI related to write operations

Comment: Thanks, Gael ! You are great as always!